# problem in show message set_flashdata with div in codeigniter?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

i want when there is value "flashdata" echo `id='error_text'` with `$this>session>flashdata('error')`. how is it?
this code have error:

```
   <?php
      isset($this->session->flashdata('error'))
      {
          "<div id='error_text'>" . $this->session->flashdata('error') . "</div>"}
    ?>
```

error:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\mehdi\system\core\Loader.php(679) : eval()'d
>   code on line 2

if use of this:

```
#error_text {
    background-color: #000000;
}
<div id="error_text"><?=$this->session->flashdata('error');?></div>
```

if `$this->session->flashdata('error')` not show message background it always is black (`#error_text{background-color: #000000;}`).

**EDIT:**

in controller:

```
if ($this->db->count_all($this->_table) == 0) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error have.');
        $error = isset($this->session->flashdata('error')) ? $this->session->flashdata('error') : FALSE; // Line 36
        redirect('admin/accommodation/insert');
        } else {
        return 0;
        }
```

in view:

```
<?php if($error){"<div id='error_text'>".$this->session->flashdata('error')."</div>"}?>
```

new error:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\application\controllers\admin\accommodation.php
>   on line 36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transfer the flashdata into variable at the first place. And do that in your controller, then send it to view. Its better to separate logic from presentation.

```
 if ($this->db->count_all($this->_table) == 0) 
 {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error have.');
    // You doesn't need that here...
    // $error = isset($this->session->flashdata('error')) ? $this->session->flashdata('error') : FALSE; // Line 36
    redirect('admin/accommodation/insert');
 } 
 else 
 {
    return 0;
 }


// Then for validate, in 'admin/accommodation/insert'
$error = $this->session->flashdata('error');

$data = array();

//...

$data['error'] = $error;
$this->load->view('someview',$data);

// And in your view file
<?php if($error) : ?>
<div id="error_text"><?php echo $error ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: my code is this: see: `$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Successfully');redirect('admin/accommodation/insert');` . how is for redirect?

Comment: i edit post and put new code in that with error, please see it and tell me what problem?

Comment: you put that line(line 36) at target controller which is `admin/accommodation/insert`